# gunicorn.service: Failed to determine user credentials: No such process

Tags: django, web-deployment, gunicorn

I keep getting an error when trying to set gunicorn with my django project

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-02-04 17:45:34 +01; 25min ago
TriggeredBy: ● gunicorn.socket
   Main PID: 754981 (code=exited, status=217/USER)

Feb 04 17:45:34 vps141106 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Feb 04 17:45:34 vps141106 systemd[754981]: gunicorn.service: Failed to determine user credentials: No such process
Feb 04 17:45:34 vps141106 systemd[754981]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step USER spawning /home/root/venv/bin/gunicorn: No such process
Feb 04 17:45:34 vps141106 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Feb 04 17:45:34 vps141106 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 04 17:45:34 vps141106 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 04 17:45:34 vps141106 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 04 17:45:34 vps141106 systemd[1]: Failed to start gunicorn daemon.
```

This is my service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/root/test
ExecStart=/home/root/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          test.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Im getting those errors

```
gunicorn.service: Failed to determine user credentials: No such process
gunicorn.service: Failed at step USER spawning /home/root/venv/bin/gunicorn: No such process
```

Now Im pretty sure I have something in /home/root/venv/bin/gunicorn I just did a

nano /home/root/venv/bin/gunicorn and got this

```
  GNU nano 4.8                                           /home/root/venv/bin/gunicorn                                                     
#!/home/root/venv/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(run())
```

so I have gunicorn installed

now with the first error, Im not sure what is causing it, the system user is called root and has sudo privileges

I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Have you fixed this ?

Comment: Have you fixed this? I am also getting the same error. If anyone know the solution let me know

Comment: also hit this problem in July 2022. rather odd as following the digital ocean tutorial and have had this configuraiton working on previous occasions, only  now my standard setup has been failing. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04